# Drop Down List not showing the correct value

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here is my class

```
Public Class TitleV_List
    Public Full_Name As String
    Public ID As Integer
    Sub New(ByVal Full_Name As String, ByVal ID As Integer)
        Me.Full_Name = Full_Name
        Me.ID = ID
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim TitleVList As New List(Of TitleV_List)


con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

sql = "Select ID, Full_Name FROM cts_TitleV_Leads WHERE IsActive = 1"

If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    con.Open()
End If

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = sql

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

If dr.HasRows = True Then
    While dr.Read

        TitleVList.Add(New TitleV_List(dr("Full_Name"), dr("ID")))
    End While
End If

If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
End If

ddlpropTitleVlist.DataSource = TitleVList
```

I check the code and the correct values are going into the dropdownlist but on the screen when I click on the dropdown Arrow all the values are:
'CTSnet.TitleV_List'

The project name is CTSnet. What am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things to make this work. First, set DisplayMember and ValueMember for ddlpropTitleVlist. Something like the following right after you set the DataSource:

```
ddlpropTitleVlist.DisplayMember = "Full_Name"
ddlpropTitleVlist.ValueMember = "ID"
```

And further, you need to be pointing those members at *properties* of your TitleV_List class:

```
Public Property Full_Name As String
Public Property ID As Integer
```

(While we're talking about stuff, I think you should remove "_List" from that class name because it's not a list of any sort. Maybe call it TitleV_Item and then your TitleVList will suggest a list of items rather than incorrectly suggesting a list of lists.)

Comment: I did add what you suggested but I am still getting the same results.